# Decoding JWT token without key in an React Native Expo App

Tags: react-native, jwt, decode

My app is currently running on expo and I need a way to decode JWT token I received from the backend. When I use `jwt.io` it doesn’t need a key to decode, but I can’t seem to find a library supporting expo that doesn’t need a key to decode. I have tried decoding it without library using the code below but it doesn't work:-

```
JSON.parse(new Buffer(token.split(‘.’)[1], ‘base64’.toString()));
```

I have tried using a few expo libraries, but all that I found needs a key to decode and if I pass an empty string to the key it just wouldn't decode.
I have also tried to decode without a library

The expected results is the object below after decoding my JWT token through `jwt.io`:

```
{
  "id": "5ce667c89133fd61e7f08c53",
  "name": "TEST Group",
  "username": "chia.wq@redtech.my",
  "type": "G",
  "iat": 1560152565
}
```

Is there any other way for me to decode without a key by using or without using a library in React Native on Expo?

Comment: The idea of JWT is that it is *signed*. Without the public key of the used public/private key pair or the shared secret it makes no sense to try to decode a JWT. You will never know if anybody changed it.

Answer (score 7):

The JWT key is only here to sign the token, so yes can extract the data without the key.

The only thing you are missing is that buffers are not encoded in Base64 but in "URL Base64".

Before passing token parts to `Buffer` you have to replace all '-' by '+' and all '_' by '/'.

```
const token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c';

const parts = token.split('.').map(part => Buffer.from(part.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/'), 'base64').toString());

const payload = JSON.parse(parts[1]);

console.log('JWT payload', payload);
```

Comment: I see ! so is this what you mean? cuz when I call this function from my app, it does go in but i am not sure why but it just doesnt log the parsedObj from my code.

Comment: decodeJwtToken(token) {
    console.log("Entered decodeJwtToken function")
    var temp = token.replace("-", "+");
    var newtoken = temp.replace("_", "/");
    
    var parsedObj = JSON.parse(new Buffer(newtoken.split(".")[1], "base64").toString())
    console.log(parsedObj)
  }

Comment: Don't use `String.replace(String, String)`, it replaces only the first occurence of the String. Use the `RegExp` version.

Comment: I see I tried changing to the RegExpo version, not sure whether I'm doing it right but this is my function, 
decodeJwtToken(token) {
    console.log("Entered decodeJwtToken function")
    var temp = token.replace(/-/i, "+");
    var newtoken = temp.replace(/_/i, "/");
    
    var parsedObj = JSON.parse(new Buffer(newtoken.split(".")[1], "base64").toString())
    console.log(parsedObj)
  }
Still, it doesnt reach the console log when I call the function tho... So I have no idea whether it works or not

Comment: thanks! helped soving my problem to decode jwt token

Answer (score 3):

My solution

1/ `npm install buffer`

2/ `import { Buffer } from "buffer"`

3/ `const parts = responseJson.token.split('.').map((part) => Buffer.from(part.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/'),'base64').toString());`