# Getting user data through an Azure AD OAuth login - React Native Expo App

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, jwt, expo

In my app, I authenticate users through an **Microsoft Azure AD Login** using **useAuthRequest**, as the [Expo Documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#azure) suggests (This login method is working successfully). Inside my request, I parse in the scopes `['openid', 'profile', 'email']`.

**I want to display data such as the users name and email inside my application, but don’t know how to get that data.**

After some research, I discovered that this data is kept inside a Token in a [JWT format](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/websites/web-development/json-web-token-jwt/), and it is possible to decode it using a simple JWT decoder package.

The problem is that I don't know how or where to get that specific Token to decode it.

Here is an extraction from my code:

```
const discovery = useAutoDiscovery(`${config.ENDPOINT_URL}`);

    const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
      {
        clientId: `${config.CLIENT_ID}`,
        clientSecret: `${config.CLIENT_SECRET}`,
        scopes: [ 'openid', 'profile', 'email'],
        prompt: 'login',
        redirectUri: "msauth.*MyBundleId*://auth",
        returnUrl: "msauth.*MyBundleId*://auth",
      },
        discovery,
        console.log(discovery)
      );
```

The `console.log(discovery)` returns two specific links that I think are worth mentioning:

```
"token_endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/*MyAppsTenantId*/oauth2/v2.0/token",
```

and:

```
"userinfo_endpoint": "https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo"
```

When entering the token_endpoint on my browser, it shows an Error message saying

> AADSTS900561: The endpoint only accepts POST, OPTIONS requests.
> Received a GET request.

and when entering the userinfo_endpoint link on my browser, it returns a hash with the following data:

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Access token is empty.","innerError":{"date":"2022-04-28T13:00:07","request-id":"*MyAppTenantId","client-request-id":"*ClientRequestId*"}}}
```

Useful links:

-[Microsoft UserInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/userinfo)

-[OpenID Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#openid-connect-scopes)

-[Active Directory Protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols)

If you have any clue, tip, or information on **how to get the JWT token containing the user data**, please share below and I will be very happy to read it and comment on.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Expo Authentication lib, but I would assume the token is present in the ```response``` of ```useAuthRequest```? I'm using `react-native-app-auth` in one of my apps to authenticate with Azure, and its ```authorize``` function returns the accessToken, refreshToken and token validity date.

Comment: Unfortunetly, the token is not present in the response. I discovered that I would probably need to make a post request to the Microsoft Graph API and get the access_token from there, but I am still getting errors. I am going to post updates as soon as I get any news on this issue. Thank you very much for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I finally solved this issue!**

I found a library called **[azure-ad-graph-expo](https://github.com/pinecat/azure-ad-graph-expo)** which does exactly what I wanted to do in a very simple way -> **No need for API callings and parsing access tokens.**

Here is an extraction from my code:

```
  const [resultData, setResultData] = useState({});

  const _handlePressAsync = async () => {
    let result = await openAuthSession(azureAdAppProps);
    setResultData({ result });
  }

  const azureAdAppProps = {
    clientId        :   `******************`,
    tenantId        :   `******************`,
    scope           :   'user.read',
    redirectUrl     :   AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({ path: "auth"}),
    returnUrl       :   "mybundleid://auth",
    clientSecret    :   `******************`,
    domainHint      :   'login.microsoftonline.com',
    prompt          :   'login'
};
```

**You must set your redirect Url in the Azure portal.**

This code worked successfully because it was tested in the app build itself instead of the Expo Go App:

- => To create a build, run `expo build:ios` or `expo build:android`
- => If you want to test it in the Expo Go app, set your localhost as a redirectUrl on the Azure AD portal and set the code as  `redirectUrl: AuthSession.makeRedirectUri()`
- => For the bundle id, you can set your own -> inside app.json create the `"scheme"` inside the `"expo:"` bracket. Bundle IDs are written as in the following pattern: `com.your-company.app-name`.

To test if my app was getting the user data, the following code was added right below the login button:

```
        {resultData ? (
          <Text>{JSON.stringify(resultData)}</Text>
        ) : 
          <Text>Nothing to see here.</Text>}
```

And here is the result, right after authenticating:
**[User Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on5Ys.png)**

If you have any question or addition to this issue feel free to comment below! :D
and thanks very much for all the help and comments in this thread!

Comment: This is now depreciated since "expo build" was discontinued. Instead, you can use "EAS Build".

Comment: Looks like the package `azure-ad-graph-expo` is not usable with typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the references can be worked around:

Firstly the error AADSTS900561 might be caused because of

- 3rd party cookies on the browser. To avoid that >Open cookie settings >Unselect
  “Block third-party cookies” , Clear your cookies.
- Or it can be due to the authorization url .please check if it is
  correct.
- According to [Microsoft docs :The error AADSTS900561](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003535#:%7E:text=AADSTS90056,were%20configured%20correctly.)

> *To redeem the code for an access token, the app should send a POST request to the /token endpoint. Also, prior to this, you should provide an authorization code and send it in the POST request to the /token endpoint.*

---

Regarding getting token and decoding ,found few references ,please check if they could help or give a clue to proceed.

Taken from  [React Native on Expo- Stack Overflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69166211/cant-get-refresh-token-using-react-native-on-expo-and-authenticating-with-micro)

```
const discovery = useAutoDiscovery('https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/v2.0');
  // Request
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: 'YOUR - CLIENT - ID',
      scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'offline_access' 'user.read
],
      redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({
        scheme: 'exp://YOUR IP ADDRESS:19000'
        }),
grant_type: ‘authorization_code’,

        // codeChallenge: 'CODE_CHALLENGE',
        // codeChallengeMethod: 'S256',
        // usePKCE: true
      },
    discovery
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (response && 'params' in response) {
        if (response.params && 'code' in response.params) {

            (async function getToken() {
                console.log('-----------------------')
                console.log(response.params.code)
                console.log('-----------------------')

                try {
                    // @ts-ignore
                    const { accessToken } = await exchangeCodeAsync({
                        code: response.params.code,
                        clientId: 'CLIENT - ID',
                        redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({
                          scheme: ' '
                          }),
                        scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'offline_access'],
                        grant_type: "authorization_code",
                        extraParams: {
                          // code_verifier: "CODE_VERIFIER",
                          code_verifier: request?.codeVerifier || '' ,
                      },
                    }, {
                        tokenEndpoint: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENNANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/token' // 
                    })

             
                    console.log(accessToken)
```

Please check each of these references:

1. [**expo-react-native-azure-ad-2| GitHub**](https://github.com/Angel-Morales-R/expo-react-native-azure-ad-2/blob/main/lib/Auth.js)
2. Also check [this SO ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70581097/expo-authentication-receiving-invalid-jwt-from-azure-ad)
3. See if this [github discussion on expo issues](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8300#issuecomment-718369087) could give an idea to get the user token.

decode:

```
   decodeJwtToken(token) {
   console.log("Entered decodeJwtToken function") 
   var temp = token.replace(/-/i, "+");
   var newtoken = temp.replace(/_/i, "/"); 
   var parsedObj = JSON.parse(new Buffer(newtoken.split(".")[1], "base64").toString()) 
   console.log(parsedObj) }
```

check if user can be extracted from token to parse >[JSON.stringify(user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546048/decoding-jwt-token-without-key-in-an-react-native-expo-app/56547391#56547391).
See [Decoding JWT token  - SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546048/decoding-jwt-token-without-key-in-an-react-native-expo-app/56547391#56547391)

& [npm:expo-react-native-azure-ad-2 | Skypack](https://www.skypack.dev/view/expo-react-native-azure-ad-2)

You can  configure the optional claims in the application token configuration if needed for other claims:
[image]

---

Just in case If [react native azure auth](https://github.com/vmurin/react-native-azure-auth) is used ,below code can give user info:

```
try {
      let tokens = await azureAuth.webAuth.authorize({scope: 'openid profile User.Read Mail.Read' })
      this.setState({ accessToken: tokens.accessToken });
      let info = await azureAuth.auth.msGraphRequest({token: tokens.accessToken, path: '/me'})
      this.setState({ user: info.displayName, userId: tokens.userId })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
```