# Advice on how to set single redirectURL for EXPO react native app for use with MS Azure AD Authentication

Tags: react-native, authentication, azure-active-directory, expo, microsoft-oauth

I'm using Expo to get started with an app which authenticates with Azure AD Oauth as per: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#azure

It works with a single redirect URL exp://host:port with Expo Go.

However, when I build the app, I simply change the redirectURL to the bundle id e.g. com.xyx.poc . . .I really don't know what redirect URL to set in the Azure Portal (app registrations) . . . .

Do I use a web redirect URL or a iOS / Android platform redirect URl? And what value do I set it to? I've tried a tonne of things e.g.

```
msauth://code/msauth.com.xyz.poc%3A%2F%2Fauth
msauth.com.xyz.poc://auth
msauth.com.xyz.poc
```

Please help. . . . I just need to know what to set up in app.json / relevant tsx where the auth component lies and what to set up in the Azure Portal / App Registrations section for redirect URL. . .

Comment: Check if this helps [Getting user data through an Azure AD OAuth login - React Native Expo App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72044215/getting-user-data-through-an-azure-ad-oauth-login-react-native-expo-app)

Comment: Hi, I've already had it working with Expo Go, but not once the Expo app is compiled to APK / iPA. . . . I quite honestly have run out of ideas on what to put as redirect URL on the Azure Portal in the Authentication settings redirect URLs. . . .

Comment: If I use <bundle_id>://auth as the redirect URL, and put it as a redirect URL in Azure, expo sends it to azure with extra ://   WHICH IS WRONG!!!!! . . . . How do I prevent expo from adding extra :// e.g. <bundle_id>://auth:// . . .  . . . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure this out after over a day of tweaking and reading. Wish it was clearer, but here goes:

I set the `redirect_uri` as follows:

```
redirect_uri: makeRedirectUri({ scheme: '<bundle_id_here>', path: 'auth' }),
```

My `expo.scheme` was set to just: `"<bundle_id_here>"`

In Azure, under App Registrations, Authentication, I put in a "web and desktop application" redirect URL as: `<bundle_id_here>://auth`

Answer (score 0):

Create web app then update inside redirect url.

Please update your redirect url inside manifest it allow @,
https://auth.expo.io/@username/app-slug

The same url you can use using manifest inside AZURE left side menu bellow authorization, directly update your url.

I had same issue while update direct url into redirect url, so use manifest tab

For more info : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/876955/azure-active-directory-app-registration-doesnt-acc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @fatihyildizhan it works!

Only for add more context if somebody needs, to get the bundle_id and not a route like expo `exp://192.168.1.48:8081/auth` we should create a development build to get the bundle_id correctly, here you can see how:

https://docs.expo.dev/build/eas-json/#development-builds

I hope it helps!